# export github commits/names to CSV with bash & jq

Tags: bash, csv, export-to-csv, jq, github-api

For a project I need to extract data from a lot of different blockchain GitHub profiles to a csv.

After browsing through the GitHub API I was able to achieve some of the necessary data being shown as txt/csv files using bash commands and jq.

Now doing all of this manually would probably take 7 days. I have a list of profiles i need to loop through saved as CSV.

The list looks like this --> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lFsewAYI7F8zSw7WPhI9E9WwR8f4G1clw1yjxY3wz_4/edit#gid=0

My approach so far to get all the repo names looks like this:

```
sample='[{"name":"0chain"},{"name":"0stateapp"},{"name":"0xcert"}]'
```

the csv belongs in here, I didn't know how to redirect it to that variable yet, but for testing purposes this was enough. If somebody knows how to, feel free to give a hint.

```
for row in $(echo "${sample}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
_jq() 
{
 echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
}

for GHUSER in $( echo $(_jq '.name')); do

  curl -s https://api.github.com/users/$GHUSER/repos?per_page=100 | jq -r '.[]|.full_name'

done

done
```

The output looks like this:

```
0chain/0chain-token
0chain/client-sdk
0chain/docs
0chain/gorocksdb
0chain/hostadmin
0chain/rocksdb
0stateapp/ZSCoin
0xcert/0xcert
0xcert/conventions
0xcert/docs
0xcert/erc721-validator
0xcert/erc721-validator-api
0xcert/erc721-validator-ui
0xcert/erc721-website
0xcert/ethereum
0xcert/ethereum-crowdsale
0xcert/ethereum-dex
0xcert/ethereum-erc20
0xcert/ethereum-erc721
0xcert/ethereum-minter
0xcert/ethereum-utils
0xcert/ethereum-xcert
0xcert/ethereum-xcert-builder
0xcert/ethereum-zxc
0xcert/framework
0xcert/framework-cert-test
0xcert/nonfungiblealliance-www
0xcert/solidity-style-guide
0xcert/techpaper
0xcert/truffle
0xcert/web3.js
```

What I need to do is use all of the above values and generate a file that contains:

- Github Profile (already stored in the attached sheet)
- The Date when accessing this information
- All the repositories belonging to that profile (code above but
  filtered)

Now the Interesting part:
The commit history

- number of commit (ID)
- number of commit (ID)
- Date of commit
- Description of commit
- person who commited
- checks passed
- checks failed

Almost the same needs to be done for closed and open pull requests although I think when solving the "problem" above solving the pull requests is the same strategy.

For the commits I'd do something like this:

```
for commits in $( $repoarray) do curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/$commits/commits | jq -r '.[]|.author.lgoin (and whatever els is needed)' done
```

basically this chart here needs to be filled

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFXiohiWNXNP8CVztFA1PFF41jn3J9sRUhYALZShsPY/edit?usp=sharing

what I need help with:

- storing my output from the first loop in a an array
- loop through that array to get the number of commits
- loop through that array to get the data to closed pull requests
- loop through that array to get the data to open pull requests

Excuse my "noobish" question.
I'm using bash/jq and the GitHub API for the time.

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but as a matter of best practice, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more reliable practices for looping over line-oriented content.

Comment: ...trying to figure out what your "immediate" problem is, though, it seems like this isn't narrowly scoped to a single, specific, narrow question. See [mcve] guidelines in our Help Center -- multi-part questions should be split into separate questions, each removing any information unrelated to that specific aspect of your problem, and each only asked after doing a search for duplicates. (When you ask a N-part question it defeats our duplicate-management mechanism, because even if we already have A, B and C answered, we may not have A+B+C answered *as part of the same question*).

Comment: For many of your questions, about how to load or loop over arrays, see [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005), with attention to the `mapfile` builtin. `mapfile -t arrayname < <(code-that-generates-one-line-per-element)` will load one array element into `arrayname` for each line emitted by `code-that-generates-one-line-per-element`.

Comment: ...anyhow, once you've factored out a narrow, specific jq or bash question -- something that can be answered without writing your whole program for you -- I'd be happy to answer it.

Comment: @charlesduffy hey charles, i'll go with your few hints first and then i'll try to narrow down what s missing. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: This question is "interesting" in that it contains so many questions at once, but in fact no real question (and no possibility to reproduce: only dead links, no example inputs, no example outputs). How is anybody supposed to answer this?